# Two Project Visual Studio Solution MVC and Web

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, single-page-application

Is it possible to have a visual studio solution arranged such that there is a:

```
x.sln
     x.Web.csproj  -pure html/js/css
     x.MVC.csproj  -routes and standard webapi
```

Where the MVC site runs and hosts the web project i.e. out of the Views/Static. on the same server.  Perhaps as a virtual directory?  That way they can be developed and tested separately but deployed and with the option to run them together.

Comment: The best I can do is create a virtual directory /MVC for the mvc project such that the / is mapped to the web project.  I was hoping for a solution that would not involve two virtual directories.